# c++ error expected initializer before ‘void’ al compilar main

Tags: c++, array, compilador

tengo una duda con una `class` en la que implemento un vector con todas sus funciones, lo que pasa es que al compilar, en el main me sale un error que no entiendo , he revisado mi código y no encuentro error.

Este es el main:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cassert>
#include "vector.hpp"
using namespace std;

int main void(){
  vector a;

  vector<int> a1(8);
  a1 = {2,3,4,8,7,6,5,1};

  vector<int> a2(8);

  a2 = {4,5,8,9,2,8,7,6};

  a.suma(a1,a2);

}
```

Este es el error:

```
7:10: error: expected initializer before ‘void’
 int main void(){
refiriéndose a `int main void()`
```

Se agradece ayuda.Gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Justamente el metodo main esta mal definido.

```
int main void(){
    //...
}
```

Debería ser:

```
int main (void){
    //...
}
```

Documentación relevante (en ingles):
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/main_function

Comment: Aunque siendo C++ sería más lógico dejarlo como `int main()`

Comment: No sería lo más lógico, @eferion , sería lo adecuado. [tag:C++] da soporte a la sintaxis `(void)` heredada de [tag:C], pero no es su sintaxis definida.

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus ya bueno... yo me refería a que es la sintaxis esperada por un programador de C++... ya sabes que yo soy más campechano con las explicaciones :P

Answer (score 1):

Si bien es válido utilizar `int main(void)` en C++, como afirma eferion en su comentario a la otra respuesta, la sintaxis más esperada en un programa de C++ es utilizar cualquiera de las siguientes declaraciones para la función `main`:

```
int main()
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
int main(int argc, char** argv)
```

Lo cual es análogo  a cuando uno espera ver las cabeceras `<cmath>`, `<cstdlib>`, etc. en lugar de `<math.h>`, `<stdlib.h>`, etc.

Quiero resaltar también que el enlace dado en la otra respuesta es sobre como declarar la función `main` en el lenguaje C (de hecho al inicio me sorprendió que una fuente tan confiable sobre C++ como es *cppreference* señalase el uso de `int main(void)` como lo más estándar en C++). Sin embargo, el siguiente [enlace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function) que sí es sobre C++ muestra que las declaraciones más apropiadas para la función `main` son las indicadas arriba. Si quieres más información, aparte del enlace dado, puedes leer esta excelente [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207223/8781554) dada en SO.

Por último, vale la pena resaltar que también hay otras declaraciones particulares dependientes del compilador. Por ejemplo, en Microsoft Visual Studio es válido declarar la función `main` de la forma: `void main()`.